# NPOI fails on second read in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filestream, npoi

In my ASP.NET Core app, I'm reading an Excel file using NPOI. Workbook is created this way:

```
public void ImportFile()
{    
    using var fileStream = new FileStream("path_to_file.xlsm", FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    var workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(fileStream);

    // all the reads and persistence stuff
}
```

And all the reads are performed like that:

```
public static DateTime ReadDateTimeAt(IRow row, int columnIndex)
    {
        var cell = row.GetCell(columnIndex, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        try
        {
            return cell.DateCellValue;
        }
        catch
        {
            // handling logic
        }
    }
```

On the first call to method `ImportFile()` it all works just fine. Then, each subsequent call to it results in an error - `NullReferenceException` is thrown in `ReadDateTimeAt` function by `cell.DateCellValue`. Only restart of the whole app helps.

Why can it be? Am I not releasing some resources properly (I suppose I do, but the only one I think I should release is the `FileStream`, which is packed up in `using` - I've also checked with ResourceManager and file is not accessed between calls)?

I can't really tell which reference is `null`. **It's not the `Cell` object itself** - I can access it's properties through debugger. Whole workbook also seems to be loaded properly (again, accessing it through a debugger).

If it's relevant, cell that fails to be read holds reference to cell on another Sheet, it's type is set to Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the first call to method ImportFile() it all works just fine. Then,
> each subsequent call to it results in an error -
> NullReferenceException is thrown in ReadDateTimeAt function by
> cell.DateCellValue. Only restart of the whole app helps.

I did reproduce your error. This should be an internal error of NPOI.

You can use the following methods to solve it.

```
 public static string GetStringValue(ICell cell)
        {
            switch (cell.CellType)
            {
                case CellType.Numeric:
                    if (DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(cell))
                    {
                        return DateTime.FromOADate(cell.NumericCellValue).ToString();
                        //try
                        //{
                        //    return cell.DateCellValue.ToString();
                        //}
                        //catch (NullReferenceException)
                        //{
                        //    return DateTime.FromOADate(cell.NumericCellValue).ToString();
                        //}
                    }
                    return cell.NumericCellValue.ToString();

                case CellType.String:
                    return cell.StringCellValue;

                case CellType.Boolean:
                    return cell.BooleanCellValue.ToString();

                default:
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

ReadDateTimeAt method:

```
public static DateTime ReadDateTimeAt(IRow row, int columnIndex)
        {
            var cell = row.GetCell(columnIndex, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK); 
            return DateTime.Parse(GetStringValue(cell));

        }
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me to finally get through this issue, which I couldn't do on my own. Just one note: for your approach to work in my case (formula cell), there needs to be an evaluator called, sth like: `if (cell.CellType == CellType.Formula) { evaluator.EvaluateInCell(cell); }` where evaluator is an XSSFFormulaEvaluator object, otherwise defult clause of switch is always chosen. It turns out that during the second read formula is unevaluated for some reason (as you said, probably an internal NPOI error - I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/issues/412) for it).